# Repeating columns based on corresponding column values and rows based on total values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
df1_given =pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col_0':[0, 3], 'col_1':[0.1, 2], 'col_2':[0.2, 0], 'col_3':[0.3, 2]})
```

The desired data frame is as follows:

```
df2_result =pd. DataFrame.from_dict({'col_0_0':[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'col_0_1':[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],'col_0_2':[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   'col_1_0':[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],'col_1_1':[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
   'col_3_0':[0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3], 'col_3_1':[0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3]})
```

I tried using .repeat() function but it did not work. The problem is to propagate/repeat columns based on corresponding column values (i.e., row2 in df_given) and rows based on total values in row2. Note that I have huge number of columns and large values in row2 in df_given in the actual dataframe.

```
df_tried = pd.DataFrame(df1_given.values.repeat(df1_given.col_0, axis=0), columns = df1_given.columns)
```

Comment: What is the logic for generating the result?

Comment: I wanna construct a cost matrix which can be generated after going through a lot of very complex steps to solve a Transportation problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df =pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col_0':[0, 3], 'col_1':[0.1, 2], 'col_2':[0.2, 0], 'col_3':[0.3, 2]})


from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(list)

cols = list(df.columns)

for i in  range (0,len(cols)):
    if (df.iloc[1,i])>0:
        for x in range(0,int(df.iloc[1,i])):
            y = str(cols[i])
            my_dict[y+'_'+str(x)].append( df.iloc[0,i])

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
print(df_2)
```

but I don't understand the logic behind you wait for 6 rows instead of 1 at the result.but I think this solves your problem.

```
df_2
Out[57]: 
   col_0_0  col_0_1  col_0_2  col_1_0  col_1_1  col_3_0  col_3_1
0        0        0        0      0.1      0.1      0.3      0.3
```